# Laravel count and return 0

Tags: sql, laravel

```
Table A:
id   name
1    Apple
2    Orange

Table B:
id  table_a_id
1       1      
2       1         
3       1
```

How can i return like? :

```
Name    count
Apple     3
Orange    0
```

I only got Apple =3 from my join sql, how can i count the orange with 0 result?

Here is my sql:

```
A::select('A.name', DB::raw('COUNT(B.table_a_id) AS count'))
    ->leftJoin('B', 'a.id', '=', 'B.table_a_id')
    ->groupBy('A.name','B.table_a_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN instead of (INNER) JOIN.

Comment: Please show your SQL query. Thanks

Comment: updated my sql, many thanks with that

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = DB::table('A')
->join('B','A.id','=','B.table_a_id')
->select('name',DB::raw('COUNT(table_a_id)')->groupBy('A.id')->get();
```

Comment: No, it will not return count 0

Comment: @TommyTang Updated.

Comment: so if i have 99 items? i don't want to hardcode the id

Comment: @TommyTang I'm adjusting it slowly please update the result for adjustment